# Is TRIM passed through a LVM-based PV Xen domU to the underlying SSD

Tags: linux, xen, lvm, ssd, trim

Scenario:
-- Debian Xen dom0
-- SSD drive setup as LVM PV/single Volume Group.
-- Debian pv_ops-based domU setup on LVM logical volume.
-- File system inside domU is ext4 with discard option enabled.

Question:
Will the TRIM command generated inside the domU pass through these layers and reach the physical SSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux supports TRIM both as a domU (through commit `ed30bf317`) and dom0 (through commit `b3cb0d6`), but only starting with the version 3.1.

Support in DeviceMapper (the kernel technology underlying LVM) is older, so it won't be the problem.

Comment: version 3.1 of what? Linux kernel?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if that was ambiguous.